# Creating radial lines from center of polygon to edge in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, polyline-creation, centroids, radius

I have a set of polygons for which I need 16 radial lines each from the centroid of the polygon to the edge (see image). So far I have only found a python script to create radial points for a circle (https://gist.github.com/goatsweater/dbdb2eafa2e12ddd39bd51e0ccbeec2b), but this does not really solve my problem.

Is there any other way to do this operation?

[image]

Comment: Is this a symbology issue, or do you need the features?

Comment: I need the features. Thus, the answer provided by BERA provides a perfect solution. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use ["Geometry by expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) followed by ["Multipart to singleparts"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgismultiparttosingleparts).

For each angle from 0 to 360-22.5 at 22.5 increments, a line is created from the centroid to a point 1000 m (adjust this) away in the direction of the angle.

This is then collected into one multiline looking like an asterisk, which is then intersected with the polygon to extract the lines inside the polygon.

```sql
intersection(
    $geometry,
    collect_geometries(
        array_foreach(
            generate_series(0,360-22.5, 22.5),
            rotate(
                make_line(
                    centroid($geometry),
                    make_point(
                        x(centroid($geometry)), 
                        y(centroid($geometry))+1000
                        )
                    ),
                @element,
                centroid($geometry)
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

[image]